# Meteor 1.3 toastr package usage

Tags: javascript, meteor

I need a hand with this meteor package: [toastr](https://atmospherejs.com/chrismbeckett/toastr). I installed it but do not know how to use it. I just did what the author of the package said but it does not work. In the console (Chrome) I see an error message: "toastr is not defined".

After installation I am just doing this to test it:

```
toastr.success("All good", "Dude");
```

I am using meteor 1.3.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Are you sure it was successfully added?

Comment: You made me doubt so I re-check. It was not added. I don't know why if when I added it, it shows me the right message. Anyway after add it, all good. Thanks a lot